# Handle iOS home button press in as3

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, button, handle, keycode

I need help detecting and dealing with the home button being pressed on a iPhone/iPod Touch running an AIR app.  I tried

```
NativeApplication.nativeApplication.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, handleKeys, false, 0, true);

function handleKeys(event:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.HOME) {
         //do something
    }
}
```

without luck. Any ideas?  Specifically, I want to prevent the app from closing when the home button is pressed.

Comment: You should not prevent the app from closing/moving to background when the iOS home button is pressed.  If the user clicks the home button, they intend to go to the home screen.  Instead, you should quickly save state in response to the DEACTIVATE event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import flash.events.Event;

addEventListener(Event.ACTIVATE, activateListener);
addEventListener(Event.DEACTIVATE, deactivateListener);

private function activateListener(e:Event):void{
        //do something when awakened

}


private function deactivateListener(e:Event):void{
        //do something when home button is pressed.

}
```

Comment: When I implemented your code with e.preventDefault(); wrapped in the deactivateListener function, it had no effect on preventing the app from closing.  Am I going about preventing the app from closing the wrong way?

Comment: You cannot prevent the app from deactivating. All you can do is action something just before deactivation begins.